# $X \sim$ Uniform$(0, 1)$ and $Y\sim$ Uniform$(0, 1)$ compute $P(X+Y\ge0.5)$

Tags: random-variables

$X\sim$ Uniform$(0, 1)$ and $Y\sim$ Uniform$(0, 1)$ compute $P(X+Y\ge0.5)$

I tried to mark $Z=X+Y$ therefore $Z\sim N(0,2)$

$$P(X+Y\ge0.5) = 1- P(X+Y<0.5) = 1- P(Z<0.5) = f_z(0.5)\\ = \frac1{(2\sqrt{\pi}) } \times \exp(-1/4\times\sqrt2)$$

not sure if it is correct.

Thanks

Comment: No - it is not correct. $Z$ does not have a normal distribution.

Comment: Without knowing the joint distribution, you can't conclude anything (maybe they are independent ?)

Comment: so what is true about z ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: In this homework-type question, $X$ and $Y$ are probably assumed to be statistically independent. My answer assumes this, although you didn't state it explicitly.

State the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ (hint: it's constant $1$ in a square and $0$ otherwise) and calculate $1 - P(X + Y < 0.5)$ instead. Identify the area of duples in the square $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$ that fulfill $x + y < 0.5$ and calculate the probability by calculating the area of the resulting trianlge (easy).

P.S.: As mentioned by Henry, your assumption $N(0,2)$ is bogus indeed.

Comment: You cannot find the joint distribution function 
 of $(X,Y)$ or the distribution function of $X$ and $Y$ from the individual distribution functions without further assumptions.

Comment: True, but in this homework type question, $X$ and $Y$ are almost certainly intended to be iid. Even if not stated explicitly.

Comment: Added a disclaimer to my answer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but I am stack in the computation itself. by the definition of the pdf .
I can agree that z!~N(0,2) but it is not helpful even though